# Problema com quebras de linhas em sistema de busca

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de busca em PHP sem utilizar banco de dados e ele funciona muito bem, exceto quando há quebras de linhas. Como posso resolver isso?
index.php

```
<form action="busca.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="s"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

busca.php

```
<?php
$pesq = (isset($_GET['s'])) ? trim($_GET['s']) : '';
if(empty($pesq)) {
echo 'Digite no campo de busca.';
}
else {
$index = "index.php";
$busca = glob("posts/conteudo/*.txt", GLOB_BRACE);
$lendo = "";
$conteudo = "";
foreach($busca as $item) {
if($item !== $index) {
$abrir = fopen($item, "r");
while(!feof($abrir)) {
$lendo = fgets($abrir);
$conteudo .= $lendo;
$lendo .= strip_tags($lendo);
}
if(stristr($lendo, $pesq) == true) {
$dados = str_replace(".txt", "", $item);
$dados = basename($dados);
$titulo = file_get_contents("posts/titulo/$dados.txt");
$result[] = "<a href=\"posts/postagem$dados.php\">$titulo</a>";
unset($dados);
}
fclose($abrir);    
}
}
if(isset($result) && count($result) > 0) {
$result = array_unique($result);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($result as $link) {
echo "<li>$link</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
}
else {
echo 'Nenhum resultado na busca.<br /> Tente <b><label for="busca">pesquisar por palavras-chave diferentes</label></b> ou <b><label for="google">busque no Google</label></b>.
<br />
<form action="https://www.google.com.br/search" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Busca no Google..." id="google" />
</form>';
}
}
?>
```

Por exemplo, se num dos arquivos em que é feita a busca pela palavra "bom" possuir o seguinte trecho "bom dia", funciona normalmente e o sistema consegue listar o arquivo. Porém, se eu buscar por "bom" num arquivo em que exista o trecho "bom
dia" (com uma quebra de linha entre as palavras), o sistema não funciona e não lista o arquivo.

Comment: Como as quebras de linhas atrapalha? como deveria ser?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta, explicando, desculpa

Comment: Ali a sua expressão regular, deve faltar a condição para o caso de aparecer uma quebra depois da palavra.

Comment: Já agora a quebra de linha é '\n' ou '<br>'?